# Unarchiving a dictionary with unarchiveObjectWithFile using swift

Tags: swift

I am facing problem with the data that I got from using unarchiveObjectWithFile. I send a dictionary for archiving. The data, I got shows the value while debugging but I can't extract the exact value for key from the data. Always getting nil value

Here is my code

```
class Person : NSObject, NSCoding {
struct Keys {
    static let Name = "name"
    static let Age = "age"
}

var name: [String] = []
var age: [Int] = []

init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
    name = dictionary[Keys.Name] as! [String]
    age = dictionary[Keys.Age] as! [Int]
}

func encodeWithCoder(archiver: NSCoder) {
    archiver.encodeObject(name, forKey: Keys.Name)
    archiver.encodeObject(age, forKey: Keys.Age)
}

required init(coder unarchiver: NSCoder) {

    if let namesList = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Name) as? [String] {
        name = namesList
        print("name\(name)")
    }
    if let agesList = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Age) as? [Int] {
        age = agesList
        print("age \(age)")
    }
    super.init()
}
}

// View controller 
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let persons: [String:AnyObject] = [
        "name" : ["a","b","c"],
        "age" : [2,3,4]
    ]

    let personObj = Person(dictionary: persons)
    NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(personObj, toFile: "/Users/shuvo/Desktop/Data.json")

    let responseObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile("/Users/shuvo/Desktop/Data.json") as? Person

    if let unwrapData: AnyObject = responseObject {
        let nameArr = unwrapData["name"] as? [String]
        let ageArr = unwrapData["age"] as? [Int]
        print("age \(ageArr) name \(nameArr)")
    }
}

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
 super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are archiving the `Person` object and not the `[String: AnyObject]`.

You can either archive the `Person`, and extract it as a `Person` or archive the `[String: AnyObject]` and extract that. You can't use both as they are different types.

If you want to archive the `Person` object, make sure you implement the `NSCoding` protocol and have something similar to this in your `Person` class...

```
func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    aCoder.encode(age, forKey: "age")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! [String]
    self.age = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "age") as! [Int]
}
```

After that, you can just do...

```
if let responseObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: path) as? Person {
    // You can use `responseObject` as a `Person` object here... 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it took me long to figure out how to accept an answer.